# How to Update value of a Model with another Model's value in Django

Tags: python, django

```py
class Trade(models.Model):
    pips = models.FloatField(default=0)
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    new_balance = FloatField(default=0.0)
...

class Summary(models.Model):
    winning_trades = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    account_balance = FloatField(default=0.0)
...
```

When a user post a request he/she will populate the Trade model, this will update the summary model and send back to the user new summary data. How can I do this in an elegant way?

Comment: Not sure what is the question here. Are you looking for Django Signals? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/

Comment: I'm looking for a way to Update Summary when data arrive on trade model. To simplify, all data in trade table are computed on the sumary. For exemple trade1.new_balance + trade2.new_balance = account_balance. If these are only 2 data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely looking for [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/). You'd want your `Trade` model's `create` event to trigger a `post_save` signal that a listener will receive and process.

Assuming you have saved your models in a file `models.py`,

Create a file `signals.py` with the following:

```py
# code
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Trade, Summary
 
 
@receiver(post_save, sender=Trade)
def update_summary(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # query to update Summary as needed
```

You'll have to add the signals to your app config.

in your `apps.py` of the relevant app, add the following:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig
 
class AppnameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'appname'
 
    **def ready(self):
        import appname.signals**
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I will encourage you to create a transaction to perform these two actions. If the second one fails, your database will remain consistent.

Then, Django allows you to [override the model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) such as `save`. You should try that with something like the following:

```
class Trade():
  ...
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    with transaction.atomic():
      super.save()
      update_summary()
```

Then, in the view, you could query for the recently updated `Summary` and return it.

```
class TradeViewSet():
  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    trade = Trade.create(request.data)
    updated_summary = get_summary(user.id)
    response = SummarySerializer(updated_summary)
    return Response(response)
```

Comment: I'm pretty new in Django so, I need to check each of these function , thank you.

Comment: So update_summary() is a function inside The model?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, but the code I provided is a pseudo-code. in update_summary you will need to update the summary as you would normally do.